# Typegoose Mongoose Enum error - Array of strings

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs, typegoose

I have an enum:

```
export enum Careers {
  WEB_DEVELOPMENT = 'Web Development',
  MOBILE_DEVELOPMENT = 'Mobile Development',
  UI_UX = 'UI/UX'
}
```

This is the mongoose property

```
 @Prop({ type: [String], enum: Careers })
  careers!: Careers[];
```

However after creating the first item in the db, if I want to create a second, I get an error
`MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: devcamp.bootcamps index: careers_1 dup key: { careers: "Business" }`

Not sure what the problem is. I just want to be able to create multiple items in my db and the `Careers` should be an array of strings

Comment: The Error provided does not seem to match the example code given, also it is likely you have defined a `@Index` on the class (or some parent class) with the path to `careers` with option `unique: true`, it also seems like you have existing data in the collection which is a single string (not a array of strings). mongoose does not retroactively correct documents unless loaded and manually processed and saved.

Answer (score 2):

Since the enum that will be used is a string enum, I don't think it is necessary to assert or override the selections from array as being of type string. So remove that `type: [String]` from the @prop.

```js
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose'

export enum Careers {
  WEB_DEVELOPMENT = 'Web Development',
  MOBILE_DEVELOPMENT = 'Mobile Development',
  UI_UX = 'UI/UX'
}

export class SampleClass {

  @prop({ enum: Careers })
  public careers!: Careers
  
  //...
}
```

OR

```js
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose'

export class SampleClass {

  @prop({ enum: ['Web Development', 'Mobile Development', 'UI/UX'] })
  public careers!: Careers
  
  //...
}
```

Happy coding!